# Using fastlane match gives me: your developer account needs to be updated

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, fastlane, apple-sign-in

I'm using fastlane in my react native app. I am following the documentation in https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/ and everythinhg works fine here. I use the command "`fastlane match`" and it also works, but "`fastlane match appstore`" gives me "your developer account needs to be updated".

Is there anything account related that needs to be done to fix this? There is just a bit of information about it

Comment: Can you provide us the code of `match` lane?

Comment: @Akif this was not code related after all. Account seetings did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was account related after all. When creating a new user in App Store Connect, you're prompted to sign a service agreement there, but you're not prompted to sign the Apple Developer service agreement until you actually go to https://developer.apple.com , then go to the developer options (or just click the logo at the top-left side of the page) and you will have the chance to sign it. This worked for me.